# How to add question mark popup to Liferay control panel portlet?

Tags: popup, liferay

I want to add question mark icon and help popup to my custom control panel portlet. How is it possible? Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you using normal JSPs? In that case you can just use the `<liferay-ui:icon-help/>` tag:

```
<liferay-ui:icon-help message="Help me!"/>
```

Note: You also need add the following to your JSP before using `<liferay-ui:icon-help/>`

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://liferay.com/tld/theme" prefix="liferay-theme"%>
<liferay-theme:defineObjects />
```

Comment: Great, so simple, thanks! And how to place thin into header bar with portlet name?

Answer (score 1):

Try adding the help mode for the portlet. In order to add the help mode. In your portlet.xml you should have the following

```
<init-param>
    <name>view-jsp</name>
    <value>/view.jsp</value>
    </init-param>
<init-param>
    <name>help-jsp</name>
    <value>/help.jsp</value>
</init-param>
    <expiration-cache>0</expiration-cache>
    <supports>
        <mime-type>text/html</mime-type>
            <portlet-mode>view</portlet-mode>
            <portlet-mode>help</portlet-mode>
    </supports>
```

I am assuming you are having MVCPortlet and you will place the help.jsp inside docroot folder